# Django how to show user profile picture publicly?

Tags: python, django

right now authenticated user can only see his own profile pic. I want every user can see each others profile picture. how to visible profile picture publicly:

here is my code:

**models.py:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofile")
      
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=2000,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
      profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/images/',validators=[validate_file_size,FileExtensionValidator( ['png','jpg'] )],blank=True,null=True)
```

**my class based views.py**

```
 data['user_profile']= UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I want to show every user profile pic publicly for my comment section.

**html**

```
{% for i in user_profile %}
                                         {{i.first_name}}
                                    <img {%if i.profile_pic%}src="{{ i.profile_pic.url  }}" {%else%}src="https://www.bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png"{%endif%} alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail img-circle thumb96" style="max-width: 100px;margin-left: 100px;border-radius: 50%;">
                                {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Your filter gets the profile of the user making the request so that's why it will only show the user's own profile photo. You'll need to change your logic so that it can filter another way. Perhaps via slugs in the URL?

Comment: markwalker_ thanks for your comment. I think so. Can you please show me an example ?